# What's a nicer way to say "I don't care"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

The only way I know how to say "I don't care" is «Je m'en fous» but my impression is this phrase is a little vulgar. Is there a nicer, more formal way of saying "I don't care" that's more along the lines of "I don't really mind"?

Comment: @None From that answer, would "I don't really care which one you choose" be translated as "Ce que tu choisis m'est égal"?

Comment: Oui.  *Ça m'est égal* is ok. You could also say: *choisis ce que tu veux, ça m'est égal.*  *Peu importe ce que tu choisis.*

Comment: Also: "peu m'importe."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ca m'est égal.
Peu m'importe.
Je m'en fiche (not as vulgar as "je m'en fous" but can be little bit agressive).
Peu me chaut (quite outdated and not really used, at least in France).

Comment: Il y a bien sûr une foule d'expressions richement imagées et plus ou moins vulgaires, comme : "je m'en bats l’œil." "j'en ai rien à cirer". "Je m'en bats les flancs". "Je m'en tamponne". "Je m'en tape". "Je m'en bats les c...". "Je m'en tamponne le coquillard avec une pelle à tarte avec un manche en buis". "ça m'en touche une sans faire bouger l'autre", etc.

Comment: En effet, et ce sont des expressions qui méritent d'être connues! :) Mais la manière dont je comprenais la question impliquait d'éviter la vulgarité.
J'adresse une mention spéciale à "Je m'en tamponne le coquillard avec une pelle à tarte avec un manche en buis" pour le degré de précision. :D